# No scalar data in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have been reading tensorboard documentation about scalars and I have a problem with presenting it in tensorboard.

I have pip install tensorflow in windows 10

my code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(7, name='test_variable')
tf.summary.scalar('variable', a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.summary.FileWriter('my_folder', graph=sess.graph)
    X = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(X)
```

I see there is a file in `my_folder`

in command prompt: `tensorboard --logdir=my_folder --port 6006`

out:

```
C:\Users\MM>tensorboard --logdir=my_folder --port 6006
Starting TensorBoard b'54' at http://DESKTOP-9S2D9VF:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I open browser i get:

```
No scalar data was found. 
Probable causes: etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the `summary_op` and pass the result to the `FileWriter`.
For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(7, name='test_variable')
tf.summary.scalar('variable', a)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/summary', graph=sess.graph)
    X = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(X)
    summary = sess.run(summary_op)
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary)
```

From the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard):

> Then, you can just run the merged summary op, which will generate a serialized Summary protobuf object with all of your summary data at a given step. Finally, to write this summary data to disk, pass the summary protobuf to a `tf.summary.FileWriter`.

Comment: Nicolas, thank you very much for your reply and your effort. I used your solution, however I get exact same response from tensorboard. No data at all. May I ask are there any other pre-setups to get correct results? Like i said, i just did pip install tensorflow and started to experiment with it.

Comment: The code works on my machine and I can't think of any pre-setups I could have made. Sorry to ask such a silly question, but I did change the folder to `'/tmp/summary'`, have you ran `tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/summary --port 6006`?

Comment: O.K. thank you. Yes I have seen your changes and i have put it back to my_folder. O.k. I'll do further investigation, but thank you for your help.

Comment: For some reason, your code works now after two months:) Thank you.